# hazard rate ratio and confidence intervals with zero events

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, hazard

Apologies if this has been asked; I haven't been able to easily find a related thread.

I'm doing a survival analysis; how do you calculate hazard rate ratios and CIs when there are 0 events in one group?

In one sense, this is a meaningless question; the estimated hazard rate in the zero-event group is 0, therefore the estimated HRR is either 0 or infinity depending on the reference.  However, we *should* be able to calculate a confidence interval based on the number and time at risk.

One potential solution I was thinking of was to add an event after the end of the observed survival curve as sort of an "upper bound"...

Any standard way of handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can report the hazards themselves.